# Remove item from wishlist when bought

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

I'm looking for a solution that when Person A shares his wishlist (by email) with Person B, and Person B decides to buy this product for Person A the product has to be removed from the wishlish of Person A.

Any suggestions?

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Well First of all Good Question...

Got rough Idea after dig into CoreCode...

After Submitting **Share Wishlist** it calls to `SendAction` of `IndexController` of `Wishlist` **Module**

**For Items block in Email** it calls to `wishlist/share_email_items` **Block**

You can just **extend** `wishlist/share_email_items` **Block** and **override** `getAddToCartUrl()` function

```
public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    $additional['nocookie'] = 1;
    $additional['_store_to_url'] = true;
    $wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
    $additional['code'] = $wishlist->getSharingCode();
    return parent::getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

Use `controller_action_postdispatch` to capture `checkout_cart_add` (when adding single product to cart from wishlist) and `wishlist_shared_index`

find `code` from parameter on above **observers**

```
$code=$this->getRequest()->getParam('code');
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCode($code);
$customer_id= $wishlist->getCustomerId(); //Id of wishlist-customer
```

**Set that Quote as wishlist quote in session.**

Use `sales_order_place_after` **Observer** in that get `order_id` and check in session that **current session is wishlist one or not**. If its wishlist one then **match order items with customer's wishlist** ( **whose Id got in post-dispatch observer** )